# populate list after creation of site from custom site defintion

Tags: 2010, site-definition

I need to populate a list that is created as part of a custom site definition from another source.  Ive tried using a feature receiver but it states that the list has not been created.  I guess that the featureactivated event is triggered before the list has been provisioned.  How can i get custom code to run once the site creation has been fully completed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add default data in the list instance itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListInstance Title="Equipment Availability"
                OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
                TemplateType="10001"
                Url="Lists/EquipmentAvailability-ListInstance1"
                Description="My List Instance">
    <Data>
      <Rows>
        <Row>
          <Field Name ="Title">Projector</Field>
          <Field Name ="EquipmentDescription">
            High Definition Projector with built-in speaker.
          </Field>
          <Field Name ="EquipmentAvailable">TRUE</Field>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Field Name ="Title">Wired Microphone</Field>
          <Field Name ="EquipmentDescription">Dynamic Voice Microphone.
          </Field>
          <Field Name ="EquipmentAvailable">FALSE</Field>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Field Name ="Title">Wireless Microphone System</Field>
          <Field Name ="EquipmentDescription">
            Two hand held microphones and VHF receiver system.
          </Field>
          <Field Name ="EquipmentAvailable">TRUE</Field>
        </Row>
      </Rows>
    </Data>
  </ListInstance>
</Elements>
```

Refer: [List Instance with default data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276355%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If your List is provisioned via a feature, you can add data to the list instance
check out this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/listinstance-with-predefined-data-prevent-adding-records-to-list-with-same-name) it has a sample of what you might be looking for.

Comment: Im not sure this is going to work.  The list is provisioned via a feature but it is used all over our farm.  I only need to prepopulate the list when its used on this specific site definition

Comment: Well you can try to do this:
1 - Create a feature with an instance of this list type
2 - This specific instance has the data you need.
3 - If you're working with site templates I suppose you know that you can define which features should be activated on the site creation. If you don't, let me know and I'll post an example of a site template I have.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The data loading should be in a feature. Use a WebTemplate to provision the site.

http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2010/06/15/site-definitions-vs.-webtemplates.aspx