# Add item to sharepoint list definition

Tags: list-definition

I need to add some items to sharepoint list definition, so I need to have the list with columns and items, and then allow users to create the list from the UI. How do I include items in list definition?

Comment: You can use custom list template for that. It will be available in the add new app section.

Comment: How do I do that in visual studio?

Comment: You need to create Custom Columns, Add List Definition and List Instance.
In the list instance you can Add the Items.

Comment: This link will give you some idea: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/listinstance-with-predefined-data-prevent-adding-records-to-list-with-same-name

Answer (score 4):

You can do this as follow-

- Add Site Columns to the custom Solution in the Visual Studio.
- Add The Content Type if Required.
- Create List Definitions & Associate the Content Type to the List (If required).
- Add the List Items in the List Instance by default. In the   Items Here
- Deploy this solution & you can see the List with default items.

For the reference [Click Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231593.aspx) & 
[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms466023(v=office.14).aspx) & [Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/listinstance-with-predefined-data-prevent-adding-records-to-list-with-same-name#answer-60498).

This [Link](http://www.imaginet.com/2016/how-to-create-lists-in-sharepoint-using-visual-studio-2015-step-by-step-tutorial/) will give in details step by step with the Screenshots.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I know how to do all of this. I don't want to create the list, users will create the lists with predefined items ..

Comment: Yes, You just create this & save it as an List Template.
User need to click => Add an App => Select the List Template Which you have created & uploaded to Template Gallery.
Then all the default items will be created on the creation of List by any one of user.

Comment: I need something in visual studio, as said in my question, I need it in list definition to be packaged, I don't want any manual work ..

Comment: I have not yet done this with Visual Studio, But might be there is something to do.
But as I know the List Template you need to create it as above steps and while any User create => Add an App => that time user can get the default items which are added in the list instance.

Comment: Hey, If you got answer please post it!

Comment: Hi Ram. I didn't actually.

Comment: Cool, I'll try it & get back to Answer if I can! Hope for the best! We can!

Answer (score 3):

If you add list using ListInstance then you can add items using ListInstance file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <ListInstance Title="LinkList" OnQuickLaunch="TRUE" TemplateType="170" FeatureId="Your feature id" Url="Lists/LinkList" Description="Your description">
<Data>
  <Rows>
    <Row>
      <Field Name="Title">About</Field>
      <Field Name="Description">Description</Field>
      <Field Name="LinkLocation">http://testlink.com</Field>
      <Field Name="BackgroundImageLocation">
        /sites/Images/tile_about.png</Field>
      <Field Name="LaunchBehavior">New tab</Field>
      <Field Name="Order">2</Field>
    </Row>
  </Rows>
</Data>
</ListInstance>  
</Elements>
```